# How to create relationships for product dynamic attributes?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have **Product** model which has attributes. In my case to each product can be set **3** type of attributes: **size**, **color**, **material**. For each attribute I've custom table with model:

**Models:**

1. Size
2. ProductSize
3. Color
4. ProductColor
5. Material
6. ProductMaterial

Now if I want to add a new attribute to products I must create again two new tables e.g:

1. NewAttribute
2. ProductNewAttibute

How I can solve this problem with creating dynamic attibutes table. Each attributes can have many values in my case. Which relationtions I must use and how many tables can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve your Problem with 3 Tables by using a many to many Relationship with a pivot field.

**attributes**

```
| id | name     |
|----|----------|
| 1  | size     |
| 2  | color    |
| 3  | material |
```

**attribute_values**

```
| id | value    | attribute_id|
|----|----------|--------------|
| 1  | S        | 1            |
| 2  | M        | 1            |
| 3  | XL       | 1            |
```

**product_has_attributes**

```
| product_id | attribute_id | attribute_value_id |
|------------|--------------|--------------------|
| 1          | 1            | 1                  |
| 1          | 2            | x                  |
| 1          | 3            | x                  |
```

So your `Product` Model has a attributes relation

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute')
            ->withPivot('attribute_value_id')
            ->using('App\ProductAttributes');
    }
}
```

and your `Attribute` Model has a products relation

```php
class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
            ->withPivot('value')
            ->using('App\ProductAttributes');
    }
}
```

```php
class ProductAttribute extends Model
{
    public function value()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\AttributeValue');
    }
}
```

```php
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->attributes as $attribute)
        echo $attribute->name.' - '.$attribute->pivot->value->value
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

**Edit**
Search for a `Product` with `Attribute` equals Value (untested pseudo code)

```php
Product::whereHas('attributes.value', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'size')
            ->where('value.value', '');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: How in this case can be searched products by attribute name? E.g `Product::where('size', 'XL')->get();` @JulianS

Comment: I updated my answer with an untested pseudo code. Something like this could be the solution

Comment: You should use "extends Pivot" instead of "extends Model" for the custom pivot model.